# Wordpress installed under Magento - Php not executed in widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, module

I installed Magento and under a subfolder of magento root (wp), I installed wordpress.
Everything works well, excepting that php can't be executed if it's defined in widgets.

I created this shortcode in functions.php:

```
function execute_php($html){
 if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
      ob_start();
      eval("?".">".$html);
      $html=ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
 }
 return $html;
}
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
```

This shortcode normally works. It was successfully tested on other websites.
I also installed a plugin for php exec in wordpress pages/posts/widgets. 
But the php from my widgets it's not executed.
Nothing appears, but if I select "View page source" the php source code appear in red as a normal text.

Any idea?

I'm using Fishpig Magento module for wordpress integration under Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Each widget in WordPress needs to be manually supported by WordPress Integration to work. I have added support for as many widgets as I can and in version 3.0 (out soon!), even more will be supported!

To add this functionality to your integrated blog, assuming you're using a Text widget, you would need to edit to the text widget template to find the shortcode, parse it and execute the PHP